# SQL return records based on multiple columns values

Tags: sql, filter

Let's say I have the following data:

```
Number  TagValue
1       MLB
1       NFL
2       MLB
2       NFL
3       MLS
3       NFL
4       NFL
```

I want to return the following:

```
Number  TagValue
1       MLB
1       NFL
2       MLB
2       NFL
```

The request is to look each number- tag value combo and see if it has BOTH MLB and NFL. If it does not I do not want to return it. A simple where clause will return:

```
Number  TagValue
1       MLB
1       NFL
2       MLB
2       NFL
3       NFL
4       NFL
```

I do not want this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Record 3 in the original is MLS not MLB.  He just wants to exclude 3 and 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to show the records where the number has both tags and the actual tag of the record is one of the tags, then a straight forward solution would be a disjunction of two times an equal operation and an `EXISTS`.

```
SELECT t1.number,
       t1.tagvalue
       FROM elbat t1
            WHERE t1.tagvalue = 'MLB'
                  AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                     FROM elbat t2
                                     WHERE t2.number = t1.number
                                           AND t2.tagvalue = 'NFL')
                   OR t1.tagvalue = 'NFL'
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                         FROM elbat t2
                                         WHERE t2.number = t1.number
                                               AND t2.tagvalue = 'MLB');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.number = t.number and t1.tagvalue = 'MLB') and
      exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.number = t.number and t1.tagvalue = 'NFL')
```

Comment: i just tried this and still returns results that have just one of MLB and NFL?

Comment: @skimchi1993. . . You need two `exists`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return all numbers that have both codes, you can do:

```
select number
from t
where tagvalue in ('MLB', 'NFL')
group by number
having min(tagvalue) <> max(tagvalue);
```

I see little utility in returning multiple rows in this case.

If you want numbers with only one team, then:

```
select number, max(tagvalue)
from t
where tagvalue in ('MLB', 'NFL')
group by number
having min(tagvalue) = max(tagvalue);
```